# i am not getting option to import url class

Tags: testng, appium-android

`I am created simple maven project for appium,i have imported below dependency.` 
io.appium
java-client
8.5.1



org.testng
testng
7.8.0`

dependency and my java version is java 11.0.18

`public class AppiumBasic {

```
@Test
public void appiumTest()  
{
AndroidDriver driver= new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0:1:4723"),null);
}

}
```

`i created one class and  when i mouse hover to URL ,not getting import URL option..`

Comment: try to add ```import java.net.URL;```int the beginning of your file

Comment: when i imported (import java.net.URL;) i am getting error :The constructor AndroidDriver(URL, Capabilities) is ambiguous

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue today, looks like there isn't answer for this anywhere. It most likely because of pom file we upload. Latest version causing some issue. and you can't go for most used version as well. As it might cause issue in creating Uiautomator2 class.

I used following one. it worked pretty well. if not try few other files. You will get the solution for sure.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
    <version>9.0.0-beta2</version>
</dependency>
```